# Windows 10 does not detect speakers or headphones when dual booting with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, sound, 20.04, windows, windows-10

I recently dual booted Ubuntu 20.04 on my Dell XPS 13 9343 for development reasons. After setting up the dual boot, Windows will show a red X next to the speaker icon and does not detect the laptop's speakers or anything plugged into the headphone jack. The only way I can get audio back on Windows is to fully shut down, boot into Ubuntu, fully shut down again, and boot into Windows. And even then, if the computer goes to sleep at any point, the audio will not work. This is incredibly frustrating, especially considering I work with audio on a daily basis. Is there a solution to this? Audio seems to work fine on Ubuntu.

Things I've tried:

- Reinstalling the audio drivers - I've tried this with multiple versions of the driver, including ones from the manufacturer website, and nothing changed. The Realtek audio driver is grayed out under 'show hidden devices' in device manager.
- Reinstalling pulseaudio and alsa in Ubuntu - no effect.
- Putting the computer to sleep and waking it back up again, multiple times - no effect.
- Changing BIOS settings - there weren't any to change.
- Disabling power saving features on Ubuntu - no effect.